# How to decrease the scaleX using createJS as it reach a limit?

Tags: javascript, createjs

I am using createJS and have used the scaleX property to increase the scaling size of an object like so :

`this.main_mc.fish_mc.scaleX = this.main_mc.fish_mc.scaleY += .1;`

I have already attached this to a click handler.

I was thinking how do I write a condition that once it reach more than 1.5 scale level, then it starts to decrease by .1. And then another condition that once it is lesser than 0.5 scale level, then it increases by .1 again.

Thanks for helping!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's all that you want to do, then it's pretty straight-forward, although I can see why it's a bit tricky. You basically want to use a variable to determine the 'direction' of the scaling:

```
var scaling = 1;

function clickListener(e)
{
    if (this.main_mc.fish_mc.scaleX <= 0.5){
        scaling = 1;
    } else if (this.main_mc.fish_mc.scaleX >= 1.5){
        scaling = -1;
    }
    this.main_mc.fish_mc.scaleX = this.main_mc.fish_mc.scaleY += 0.1 * scaling;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works!

What if I want to do a rollover on a button and have a scaling animation of the fish once it reaches 1.5 level then it becomes smaller. Conversely, once it reaches 0.5 level then it scales up again. 

I understand previously that you can use onEnterFrame function for Flash. How is it possible to do it now using createJS?  

Thanks once again!

Comment: I am not sure I understand entirely, but if you want to trigger an event on mouse rollover, you can use the `mouseover` event, similar with the click event, but you must enable it first with `stage.enableMouseOver()` Also, in createjs the `tick` event is equivalent with EnterFrame from Flash.